# A problem occurred configuring root project. What do I need to do?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I just created a new android project to test something separate to my main one, and this happened. I tried it several times and get the same error every time.

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'login_test'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0-release-764.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release-764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release-764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
     Required by:
         project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change version of kotlin in build.gradle under the root directory.I use 1.3.72 here

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0'
ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```